# Alternatives to using multiple reduce() functions inside a map() when handling deeply nested array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object `result` which has a property records which is an array of objects with a single sample below:

```
const result = {
  records: [
    {
      keys: ["names", "value", "country", "questions"],
      length: 4,
      _fields: [
        "123ilSE",
        [
          "Longitude:5.1193",
          "Latitude:52.3246",
          "Agreeableness:0.147083333333333",
          "Openness:0.211041666666667",
          "Neuroticism:0.168833333333333",
          "Extraversion:0.150291666666666",
          "Conscientiousness:0.187041666666666",
          "Angry:0.0441711768507957",
          "Fear:0.020498564466834",
          "Joy:0.875858068466186",
          "Sadness:0.0477884039282798",
          "Love:0.00839435961097478",
        ],
        ["Netherlands", "Netherlands"],
        [
          ["Right"],
          ["Student Loan", "None"],
          ["Not at all, i’d rather rent all assets."],
          ["Another benefit"],
          ["Every two weeks", "Yearly a few times"],
          [
            "None",
            "1 to 2 hours",
            "1 to 2 hours",
            "3 hours or more",
            "Less then 1 hour",
          ],
          ["Two to Three Times a Week"],
          [
            "1 to 2 hours",
            "1 to 2 hours",
            "3 hours or more",
            "Less then 1 hour",
          ],
          [
            "1 to 2 hours",
            "1 to 2 hours",
            "3 hours or more",
            "Less then 1 hour",
          ],
          [
            "None",
            "1 to 2 hours",
            "1 to 2 hours",
            "3 hours or more",
            "Less then 1 hour",
          ],
          ["Every two weeks", "Yearly a few times"],
          ["Two to Three Times a Week"],
          ["Every Year"],
          ["Banking & Financial Services", "Unemployed"],
          ["I don't have a car"],
          ["Netherlands", "Netherlands"],
          ["3 - 4 persons"],
          ["Maybe, it depends if nothing betters comes up"],
          ["Desktop"],
          [],
          ["I don't drive or have a car"],
          [
            "E, I can be found on social media platforms and maintain my profile but do little else.",
          ],
          ["None", "Healthcare Insurance"],
          ["None", "Hockey", "Hiking"],
          ["Hiking"],
          ["Unemployed"],
          ["1999-09-20 00:00:00"],
          ["Female"],
          ["Bachelor's degree"],
          ["Less then 20.000 EUR"],
          ["Single"],
          ["Netherlands", "Netherlands"],
          ["1399"],
          ["Prolific Participant"],
          ["English", "Dutch", "German"],
          ["Operations", "Unemployed"],
          ["None"],
          ["None"],
          ["Health & Beauty", "Clothing & Shoes", "Books", "None"],
          ["Whatsapp", "Youtube", "Instagram", "None"],
          [
            "TV (Local/Cable News Broadcast)",
            "TV (Late Night Comedy, Other)",
            "Radio (AM/FM, Internet, Satellite)",
            "Print (Newspapers & Periodicals)",
            "None",
          ],
        ],
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

I am transforming it to the following shape with a function I have:

```
const sample = [
  {
    name: "123ilSE",
    longitude: 5.1193,
    latitude: 52.3246,
    agreeableness: 0.147083333333333,
    openness: 0.211041666666667,
    neuroticism: 0.168833333333333,
    extraversion: 0.150291666666666,
    conscientiousness: 0.187041666666666,
    angry: 0.0441711768507957,
    fear: 0.020498564466834,
    joy: 0.875858068466186,
    sadness: 0.0477884039282798,
    love: 0.00839435961097478,
    country: "Netherlands",
    question1: ["Right"],
    question2: ["Student Loan", "None"],
    question3: ["Not at all, i’d rather rent all assets."],
    question4: ["Another benefit"],
    question5: ["Every two weeks", "Yearly a few times"],
    question6: [
      "None",
      "1 to 2 hours",
      "1 to 2 hours",
      "3 hours or more",
      "Less then 1 hour",
    ],
    question7: ["Two to Three Times a Week"],
    question8: [
      "1 to 2 hours",
      "1 to 2 hours",
      "3 hours or more",
      "Less then 1 hour",
    ],
    question9: [
      "1 to 2 hours",
      "1 to 2 hours",
      "3 hours or more",
      "Less then 1 hour",
    ],
    question10: [
      "None",
      "1 to 2 hours",
      "1 to 2 hours",
      "3 hours or more",
      "Less then 1 hour",
    ],
    question11: ["Every two weeks", "Yearly a few times"],
    question12: ["Two to Three Times a Week"],
    question13: ["Every Year"],
    question14: ["Banking & Financial Services", "Unemployed"],
    question15: ["I don't have a car"],
    question16: ["Netherlands", "Netherlands"],
    question17: ["3 - 4 persons"],
    question18: ["Maybe, it depends if nothing betters comes up"],
    question19: ["Desktop"],
    question20: [],
    question21: ["I don't drive or have a car"],
    question22: [
      "E, I can be found on social media platforms and maintain my profile but do little else.",
    ],
    question23: ["None", "Healthcare Insurance"],
    question24: ["None", "Hockey", "Hiking"],
    question25: ["Hiking"],
    question26: ["Unemployed"],
    question27: ["1999-09-20 00:00:00"],
    question28: ["Female"],
    question29: ["Bachelor's degree"],
    question30: ["Less then 20.000 EUR"],
    question31: ["Single"],
    question32: ["Netherlands", "Netherlands"],
    question33: ["1399"],
    question34: ["Prolific Participant"],
    question35: ["English", "Dutch", "German"],
    question36: ["Operations", "Unemployed"],
    question37: ["None"],
    question38: ["None"],
    question39: ["Health & Beauty", "Clothing & Shoes", "Books", "None"],
    question40: ["Whatsapp", "Youtube", "Instagram", "None"],
    question41: [
      "TV (Local/Cable News Broadcast)",
      "TV (Late Night Comedy, Other)",
      "Radio (AM/FM, Internet, Satellite)",
      "Print (Newspapers & Periodicals)",
      "None",
    ],
  },
];
```

This is the function `computeData` which I used to map over the array and then apply `reduce()` twice in order to get the object in the format I need. `filters` is an array which contains the keys of the final object. I am aware this is not the most efficient manner to do so, therefore I need help with improving this and not using `reduce()` twice in function `computeData`.

```
const filters = [
  "name",
  "longitude",
  "latitude",
  "agreeableness",
  "openness",
  "neuroticism",
  "extraversion",
  "conscientiousness",
  "angry",
  "fear",
  "joy",
  "sadness",
  "love",
  "country",
  "question1",
  "question2",
  "question3",
  "question4",
  "question5",
  "question6",
  "question7",
  "question8",
  "question9",
  "question10",
  "question11",
  "question12",
  "question13",
  "question14",
  "question15",
  "question16",
  "question17",
  "question18",
  "question19",
  "question20",
  "question21",
  "question22",
  "question23",
  "question24",
  "question25",
  "question26",
  "question27",
  "question28",
  "question29",
  "question30",
  "question31",
  "question32",
  "question33",
  "question34",
  "question35",
  "question36",
  "question37",
  "question38",
  "question39",
  "question40",
  "question41",
];

const computeData = ({ records } = {}) => {
  return (
    records &&
    records.map(({ _fields }) => {
      const screenName = _fields[0];
      const country = _fields[2][0];
      const userPersonality = filters.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => {
        if (idx === 0) {
          acc[curr] = screenName;
        } else if (idx >= 1 && idx <= 12) {
          acc[curr] = parseFloat(_fields[1][idx - 1]);
        } else if (idx === 13) {
          acc[curr] = country;
        }
        return acc;
      }, {});
      const questions = _fields[3];
      const finalResults = filters.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => {
        if (idx > 13) {
          questions[idx - 14]
            ? (acc[curr] = questions[idx - 14])
            : (acc[curr] = []);
        }
        return acc;
      }, userPersonality);
      return finalResults;
    })
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the array of responses, you can map them to an array of entries for the new object by using the index parameter in `.map` and concatenating with `'question'`. Then pass the result to `Object.fromEntries`.

The other properties like `"Longitude:5.1193"` can be split on `:` and also be passed to `Object.fromEntries`.

```js
const result={records:[{keys:["names","value","country","questions"],length:4,_fields:["123ilSE",["Longitude:5.1193","Latitude:52.3246","Agreeableness:0.147083333333333","Openness:0.211041666666667","Neuroticism:0.168833333333333","Extraversion:0.150291666666666","Conscientiousness:0.187041666666666","Angry:0.0441711768507957","Fear:0.020498564466834","Joy:0.875858068466186","Sadness:0.0477884039282798","Love:0.00839435961097478"],["Netherlands","Netherlands"],[["Right"],["Student Loan","None"],["Not at all, i’d rather rent all assets."],["Another benefit"],["Every two weeks","Yearly a few times"],["None","1 to 2 hours","1 to 2 hours","3 hours or more","Less then 1 hour"],["Two to Three Times a Week"],["1 to 2 hours","1 to 2 hours","3 hours or more","Less then 1 hour"],["1 to 2 hours","1 to 2 hours","3 hours or more","Less then 1 hour"],["None","1 to 2 hours","1 to 2 hours","3 hours or more","Less then 1 hour"],["Every two weeks","Yearly a few times"],["Two to Three Times a Week"],["Every Year"],["Banking & Financial Services","Unemployed"],["I don't have a car"],["Netherlands","Netherlands"],["3 - 4 persons"],["Maybe, it depends if nothing betters comes up"],["Desktop"],[],["I don't drive or have a car"],["E, I can be found on social media platforms and maintain my profile but do little else."],["None","Healthcare Insurance"],["None","Hockey","Hiking"],["Hiking"],["Unemployed"],["1999-09-20 00:00:00"],["Female"],["Bachelor's degree"],["Less then 20.000 EUR"],["Single"],["Netherlands","Netherlands"],["1399"],["Prolific Participant"],["English","Dutch","German"],["Operations","Unemployed"],["None"],["None"],["Health & Beauty","Clothing & Shoes","Books","None"],["Whatsapp","Youtube","Instagram","None"],["TV (Local/Cable News Broadcast)","TV (Late Night Comedy, Other)","Radio (AM/FM, Internet, Satellite)","Print (Newspapers & Periodicals)","None"]]]}]};

const [name, otherProps, [country], responsesArr] = result.records[0]._fields;
const output = {
  name,
  ...Object.fromEntries(otherProps.map(str => {
    const [key, val] = str.split(':');
    return [key, Number(val)];
  })),
  country,
  ...Object.fromEntries(responsesArr.map(
    (responses, i) => ['question' + (i + 1), responses]
  ))
};
console.log(output);
```

Comment: @CertainPerfomance apologies but `result` is an object where records is the array of objects. I accidentally added it as an array. I have updated the question to reflect the change.

Comment: Then you just need to remove the outer `.map` part